# Getting TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ICategory' as a type in react project when trying to import interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, types

i have interface ICategory in @src/apollo/DbInterfaces.ts, im importing it in @src/components/ModalsContent/CatalogContent.tsx. Why am i getting error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ICategory' as a type.

React broject bundling via webpack
here is webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ['./src/main.tsx'],
  module: {
    rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
  },
  plugins: require('./webpack.plugins'),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css'],
    alias: require('./webpack.aliases'),
  },
  stats: 'errors-warnings',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  devServer: {
    open: true,
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./wellfitness",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["./assets/*"],
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["./src/styles/*"],
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["./src/pages/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "tools/**/*"
  ]
}
```

i tried to import like:
`import type { ICategory } from "@src/apollo/DbInterfaces.ts";`

if i add
`"allowImportingTsExtensions":` true in tsconfig.json
appears one more error:
TS5096: Option 'allowImportingTsExtensions' can only be used when either 'noEmit' or 'emitDeclarationOnly' is set.